# iOS IKEV2 VPN error: why cannot I connect?

Tags: ios, swift, vpn

I created my own VPN server(IKEV2) and I successfully run it on my iPhone by the Settings.(see the screenshot):
[image: Settings config screenshot]

Then, I want to run the VPN with the same config in the iOS application.

I wrote this config:

```
let p = NEVPNProtocolIKEv2()

p.useExtendedAuthentication = true
p.serverAddress = "133.37.212.77"
p.remoteIdentifier = "133.37.212.77"
p.authenticationMethod = .none
KeychainWrapper.standard.set("mypassword", forKey: Configuration.KEYCHAIN_PSK_KEY)
let secret = KeychainWrapper.standard.dataRef(forKey: Configuration.KEYCHAIN_PSK_KEY)
    
p.sharedSecretReference = secret
```

But when I try to start the connection, nothing happens...

What could be the reason? Why does it run fine with standard iOS OS abilities, but it doesn't from the app?
Thanks!

Comment: When I try to connect - I receive the Error Domain=NEVPNErrorDomain Code=1 error